# Node.js right way to use multiple callbacks

Tags: node.js, callback

I am a newbie in Node.js so sorry.

In my code I am using API from some service. Basically it is many callbacks. These callbacks provide values from service that i need to use in another callbacks.

If it was synchronous manner then I would write as follows:

```
var value1 = 10;
var value2 = 0;
var value3 = '';
var value4 = '';

api.method1((error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        // some code
    }

    value2 = data.value1FromApi / value1;    
});

if (value2 > 0) {
    api.method2(value2, value1, (error, response) => {
        if (error) {
            // some code
        }

        value3 = response.value2FromApi;
        value4 = response.value3FromApi;
    });

    // Check status
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (value4 !== 'some status') {
            api.method3(value3, (error, response) => {
                value4 = response.value4FromApi;
            });

            // wait(1000);
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (value4 !== 'some status') {
        api.method4(value3, (error, response) => {

        });
    }
    else {
        // similar code as above
    }
}
```

I know that it is wrong code, because after first callback `value2` will be **undefinied**.

Tell me what technology or what techniques i need to apply in order to solve that callback sequence?

Comment: You can have a look at Promises. Instead or “return” you will resolve the variable or object you will get from the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to chain many requests you need to use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

```js
var method3CalledTimes = 0;
const api = { // Replace api with real API calls
  method1: function() { 
      return Promise.resolve({ value1FromApi: 1 }); 
  },
  method2: function() { 
      return Promise.resolve({ value2FromApi: 2, value3FromApi: 3 }); 
  },
  method3: function() { 
      if (method3CalledTimes++ <= 3) // for demo
          return Promise.resolve({ status: "not-correct-status-yet" });
      return Promise.resolve({ status: "correct-status" }); 
  },
  method4: function() { 
      return Promise.resolve("Success"); 
  }
};

var value1 = 10,
    value2, 
    value3, 
    value4;

api.method1()
  .then(function(data) {
    value2 = data.value1FromApi / value1;
    
    if (value2 <= 0) 
      return Promise.reject("v2 is non-positive");      
    
    return api.method2();    
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    value3 = data.value2FromApi;
    value4 = data.value3FromApi;
    return Promise.all([api.method3(), api.method4()]);
  })
  .then(function() {   
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var tryCount = 10;

      function checkStatus() 
      {
        console.log("Trying to call method3(). Attempts left: " + tryCount);
        api.method3()
          .then(function(data) {
            console.log("Status response: " + data.status);
            if (data.status === "correct-status") {
              console.log("Valid status, resolving...");
              resolve(data.status); // status did change
            } else {
              if (tryCount-- <= 0) { // if no tries left
                console.log("Invalid status, no attempts left. Failing...");
                reject("statusnotchanged"); // status didn't change after N attempts
              } else { // if we have tries
                console.log("Invalid status, we have attempts. Trying again...");
                setTimeout(checkStatus, 1000); // try again in 1 second
              }
            }
          })
          .catch(reject); // if error - reject
      }    

      checkStatus(); // call once, then it will call itself with setTimeout      
    });
  })
  .then(function(newStatus) {
    console.log("Complete! New status = " + newStatus); 
  })
  .catch(function(r) {
    if (reason === "statusnotchanged") {
      // handle this specific reason if needed
    }
    console.error(r);
  });
```

This code is just an example, it shows the idea. Your code sample intention is pretty unclear, so I couldn't optimize it.

See how error handling becomes easier by Promise. Any reject within a chain will result into `.catch` execution. Try to set `value1` to 0 to see what happens.

Comment: OK! Thanks to all guys for `Promise`. As to loop. I needn't to wait for method3 10 times, instead i need to check every time in loop whether or not change status. And if status was changed i need immediately call method 4. Is this possible?

Comment: @Konstantin You may use `new Promise()` and implement custom resolve-reject logics. `setTimeout` will help you to wait for result. Please, see the updated answer.

Comment: @Konstantin I have updated my solution. For demo purposes it now returns incorrect status for first 3 calls, and then returns valid status. As the result, after the first succesful call we stop trying and complete execution.

Comment: Yeldar, tell me am i right i need to add real code of service api right in const declaration?

Comment: Yes, you need to implement API calls there. User Fix3r has provided example method in "External API calls".

Answer (score 5):

You need to handle this in async way. You can try this:

```
api.method1((error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        // some code
    }

    value2 = data.value1FromApi / value1;
    if (value2 > 0) {
        api.method2(value2, value1, (error, response) => {
            if (error) {
                // some code
            }

            value3 = response.value2FromApi;
            value4 = response.value3FromApi;
            // Check status
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                if (value4 !== 'some status') {
                    api.method3(value3, (error, response) => {
                        value4 = response.value4FromApi;
                        if (value4 !== 'some status') {
                                    api.method4(value3, (error, response) => {

                                    });
                                }
                        else {
                            // similar code as above
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }

        });
    }
});
```

Basically all the callbacks have to be nested within each other

Answer (score 1):

`value2` is `undefined` because it is assigned in an asynchronous function. The usage of `value2` happens before the function is executed.

You may get some knowledge about JavaScript [EventLoop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) for better understanding.

PS. There are many ways to deal with async functions and callback hells, for example [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), [async](https://github.com/caolan/async), [co](https://github.com/tj/co), [async & await in node 8](https://medium.com/@Abazhenov/using-async-await-in-express-with-node-8-b8af872c0016).

Take a look at http://callbackhell.com/ for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently while learning node.js.

I have a file that does calls to an external API and my server sends the response as json object when the user request a route.

---

### EXTERNAL API CALLS

var connection {user:"user", password:"password"} 
//this is just an example of my connection object

```
exports.getUsers = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
          var params = {search_string:""};
          var users  = [];
          connection.Users.get(params, function(error, response){
               var user;
               for(let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++)
               {
                   if(response.data[i].name=="user"
                   {
                       user = response.data[i];
                   }
               }
                   users.push({user});
               resolve(users); //return the user object
            });
        });
     };
```

---

### NODE.JS SERVER

```
const request = require('./requests.js'); //file with my external api calls

app.get('/users', function(req, res){
     requests.getUsers()
     .then(function(users){
          res.contentType('application/json');
          res.send(JSON.stringify(users));
      })
     .catch(function(err){
          console.log(err);
     });
  });
```

If you use PROMISE, the function will wait until you get the required value before it continues.

.THEN you will be able to send that result as you want to the user calling your api.

At the MDN documentation you will find absolutely everything about JS and it is amazingly helpful.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

---

### EDIT

Reading a bit more about promises I found that other link, it can be useful as well:
http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html